# Show that there are polynomials of degree $m-k$ whose subsets of $EG(m,2)$ are not flats

Tags: euclidean-geometry, boolean-algebra, information-theory, coding-theory, reed-muller-codes

I need help in showing that the converse of the theorem "if $F$ is an $(m-k)$-flat in $EG(m,2)$, the the corresponding Boolean polynomial $P_F$ has degree $k$" does not hold.
Or that is, "that there are Boolean polynomials $p(x_1,...,x_m)$ of degree $m-k$ whose corresponding subsets $F_p$ of $EG(m,2)$ are not flats."

Hint given in the book: Consider quadratic polynomials in three variables. Recall that in $EG(3,2)$, the hyperplanes correspond to the linear polynomials, so that if a quadratic polynomial does correspond to a flat, it must be a line (1-flat).

Since $EG(m,2) = \Bbb{F}_2^m$, then $m$ is the length of the codewords, or vectors, in a vector space $S$. And by definition, if $S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{F}_2^m$ with $dim(S)=k$, then any coset $b+S$ is called a $k$-flat.

I wanted to show this proof by using an example.

Consider $EG(3,2) = \Bbb{F}_2^3$.

By a theorem, in $EG(3,2)$, the $(m-1)=(3-1)=2$-flats, or hyperplanes, correspond to the linear Boolean polynomials (degree $m-k=3-2=1$).

Thus, if there exists a quadratic (degree $2$) Boolean polynomial that corresponds to a flat, by definition, it must correspond to a $1$-flat ($m-k=2 =>3-2=k=1$).

However...

This was my sad attempt at the proof, by using this method (suggested in my textbook) I get stuck because I am unsure on how this relates to proving the statement. Should I show that the quadratic polynomial cannot correspond to a $1$-flat? And thus since it cannot correspond to a $1$-flat, any other subset it corresponds to will not be a flat?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about $k$?  This is definitely not true for $k=m-1$, for instance...

Comment: Thank you for commenting! No, no assumptions for $k$. And I'm sorry, but could you specify what would not be true for $k=m-1$? @EricWofsey

Comment: Well, if $k=m-1$ your polynomials are linear, so their vanishing sets are flats by definition.  (Unless I'm horribly confused about some definitions; this is not the notation I'm used to.)

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. But I think the way to approach the proof is to find just one example for a subset not to be a flat, but please let me know if I am horribly confused :)

Comment: Well, the statement as written cannot be proved or disproved, since it is ambiguous.  What is $m$?  What is $k$?  The truth of the statement depends on what $m$ and $k$ are.

Comment: If you fix any particular $(m,k)$, then finding one example would be enough to prove the statement for that particular $(m,k)$.  But unless you add existential quantifiers (there exists $m$ and there exists $k$) to the start of the statement, this does not prove the original statement, since it is really a separate statement for every possible $(m,k)$.  And the usual convention would be that unstated quantifiers are assumed to be universal, not existential.

Comment: It's like if someone asked you to prove that there exists an integer $m$ such that $n=2m$.  Obviously, to prove such a thing (or for it even to be meaningful to say whether it is true), you need to know what $n$ is! (And it is not true for all $n$.)

Comment: Oh yes, you're completely right. Since EG(m,2) = \Bbb{F_2^m), then m is the length of the codewords, or vectors in a vector space S. And then we know by definition that if S is a subspace of $\Bbb{F_2^m)$ with dim(S)=k, then any coset b+S is called a k-flat, so K is the dimension of S. But in this case, the book gave the hint to use EG(3,2) = \Bbb{F_2^3). Also there appears to be a problem with my comment...

Comment: I would suggest you share the _exact_ wording of the entire problem (and any preceding text that might be relevant to the assumptions).  I would be surprised to see the wording you used in a book (though there do exist poorly-written books...).

Comment: I added the hint, but I am afraid to say that I had already written the question word for word. I will also move the definitions in the comments to the problem itself

Comment: When I say "the exact wording of the entire problem", I mean that literally.  You did not include the exact wording of the entire problem!  The reference to disproving the converse of Theorem 6.2.8 is very relevant to clarifying the intended quantifiers in the question. (I was able to find the source by googling the text of the hint.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was midway to typing that in, I will add that asap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are way overthinking this.  Stop thinking in abstract generalities and just write down an example!  Try out some really simple quadratic polynomials in three variables, and see what their vanishing sets are.  With a little trial and error you can find one whose vanishing set is not a flat.

In fact, I would consider the given hint kind of silly, since there are even easier counterexamples.  You could instead try a polynomial of degree $0$, in any number of variables.  Or, you could try a quadratic polynomial in only two variables.

Comment: Wow that's the third time those hints just wasted everyone's time lol Thank you very much for your help and patience! It was much appreciated!

Comment: Would the polynomial $p=x_2+x_1x_3$ work? Since I think the corresponding $F_p$ is $F_p=\{010,011,101,110,111\}$ and if you add the first four elements you do not get the fifth element

Comment: Assuming $F_p$ means the set of points where $p$ is $1$ (I was assuming it was the set of points where $p$ is $0$), $111$ is not an element of $F_p$. Removing it, you still don't get a flat though.